# How to trigger the removal of old cached values using MemoryCache as it was intended

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I am using the following code in order to ensure that I only go to the database once for my Agent data and for the cached data to be **refereshed** when the `contractId` being passed in changes.

```
public static AgentCacher
{
    private IAgentDal AgentDal;
    private readonly ObjectCache AgentObjectCache;
    private string LastContractId;

    public AgentCacher(IAgentDal agentDal)
    {
        this.AgentDal = agentDal;

        // Get the instance of the cache
        this.AgentObjectCache = MemoryCache.Default;
    }

    public List<Agent> GetAgentsForContract(int contractId)
    {
        // Set the key to be used for the cache
        var cacheKey = contractId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        // Has the contract ID changed?
        if (this.LastContractId !== cacheKey)
        {
            // Remove the item from the cache
            this.AgentObjectCache.Remove(this.LastContractId);
        }
        // Are the agents for this contract ID already in the cache?
        else if (this.AgentObjectCache.Contains(cacheKey))
        {
            // Return agents list from the cache
            return
                this.AgentObjectCache.Get(cacheKey) as
                List<Agent>;
        }

        // Go to the database and get the agents
        var agentsFromDatabase = this.AgentDal.GetAgentsForContract(contractId);

        // Add the values to the cache
        this.AgentObjectCache.Add(cacheKey, agentsFromDatabase, DateTimeOffset.MaxValue);

        // Set the contract Id for checking next time
        this.LastContractId = cacheKey;

        // Return the agents
        return agentsFromDatabase;
    }
}
```

This works OK, but I feel like I'm probably not using the `MemoryCache` in the way it was intended to be used.

How can I `trigger` the removal of the values that I add to the cache to clear out the old values when the `contractId` changes, do I have to use `ChangeMonitor` or `CacheItemPolicy` that can be passed in when adding to the cache?

I've been struggling to find examples as to how it should be used properly.

Comment: Thanks for the vote down and no comment!

Comment: I upvoted to undo their meaningless downvote.

Comment: @Krythic Thank you, very kind of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic looks right. However you are managing cache lifetime yourself instead of relying on built in expiration system technics. For instance instead of you to check if there is a new contractId, remove old one and add new one, I think you should cache for as many contractIds as needed, but to have for example absolute expiration for 1 hour. For example if there is contractId == 1 then you will have cache with cache key 1 and if another request asks for contractId == 2 then you will go to db pull contract information for id == 2 and store it in the cache for another absolute expiration 1 hour or so. I think this will be more efficient instead of you manage cache (add, remove) yourself.

You also need to consider locking data when you add and remove data from the cache in order to eliminate race condition.

You can find good example on how to do it:

[Working With Caching in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/working-with-caching-in-C-Sharp/)

[Using MemoryCache in .NET 4.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/756423/How-to-Cache-Objects-Simply-using-System-Runtime-C)

Comment: Thank you, you've made some very valid points there.  I think we're going to end up just letting the values expire after a certain time, that sounds more sensible that managing the removal too.